# Series with power of generalized harmonic number $\displaystyle\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\left(H_k^{(s)}\right)^n x^k$

Tags: sequences-and-series, special-functions, harmonic-numbers, polylogarithm

It's possible to generalize these series?
$$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}H_k^{(s)}x^k=\frac{\operatorname{Li}_s(x)}{1-x}$$
$$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}H_k^2 x^k=\frac{\ln(1-x)^2+\operatorname{Li}_2(x)}{1-x}$$
Where:
$$H_k:=\sum_{j=1}^{k}\frac{1}{j}\text{ are the harmonic numbers}$$
$$H_k^{(s)}:=\sum_{j=1}^{k}\frac{1}{j^s}\text{ are the generalized harmonic numbers}$$
$$\operatorname{Li}_s(z)\text{ is the polylogarithm}$$
I'd like to know if there are formulas for series like this:
$$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\left(H_k^{(s)}\right)^n x^k\qquad \text{where }n\in\mathbb{N}$$

Comment: Second equality do you mean $H_k^{(2)}$ or $H_k^2$ ?

Comment: In the second equation it is $H_k^2$

Comment: Have you tried an expression for $n=2,3,4$ at least.